# Python 2 Odd or Even numbers

Tags: python

I'm trying to fix a problem like if a number is odd print smth. if even print smth. else. My Python code is as follows ;

```
import sys
import math


N = int(raw_input().strip())

def dec(num):
    if num % 2 == 0 and num != 0:
         print 'Not Odd'
       elif num == 0:
        print 'Case Zero'
       else:
        print 'Even'

dec(N)
```

Why I can't compile this code ?

Comment: So what error do you get? Your indentation is *way off*, is that how you have it in your editor?

Comment: This is a Hackerrank challenge https://www.hackerrank.com/challenges/30-conditional-statements

I get invalid syntax error by the way

Comment: "Why I can't compile this code ?" Because you're probably running it with the interpreter.

Comment: @Rightleg: the interpreter will compile it. I'm not sure what your remark is supposed to convey.

Comment: @MartijnPieters Most Python implementations are only interpreters, not compilers. Some seldom implementations do perform a just-in-time compilation though, but Python is in its most frequent form an interpreted language, not a compiled one. [Is Python Interpreted or Compiled?](http://softwareengineering.stackexchange.com/questions/24558/is-python-interpreted-or-compiled)

Comment: @MartijnPieters Ok, I checked your profile, and you might think I'm a bit pretentious to think I'm teaching you something. Anyway, just wanted to stress the fact that Python is interpreted and not compiled (in a general meaning, comparing with C etc)

Comment: @Rightleg: Python compiles source code to bytecode, then interprets the bytecode. When it comes to interpreters, there always is *some* compilation. A `SyntaxError` is always a compile-time error (although `import`, `exec()`, `execfile()`, `eval()` or `compile()` can trigger a compilation step for the code being loaded).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You have a `'` within the string enclosed by `'`s.
Try:

```
print 'Zero can\'t be odd or even!'
```

As I see, your indent is bad as well.
Pleas align the elif and else below the if.

You also have a not syntactical problem.
"Not even" and "Odd" are the two possibilities for you which is bad.

I've corrected these errors for you:

```
def dec(num):
    if num % 2 == 0 and num != 0:
        print 'Even'
    elif num == 0:
        print 'Zero can\'t be odd or even!'
    else:
        print 'Odd'

for N in range(5):
    dec(N)
```

One more thing is that you should think about the question about 0 wheter you really want to say that it's not even.
Ask your math teacher about this.

Comment: explained everything well .About the zero : I was just trying to say in this program I don't wanted to label zero that's all I know zero is even.